# Change hidden input field value according to select options

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a script for changing the hidden input value according to selected options.

I have hindi data stored on a variable and I need to pick this hindi data according to english data selected in select feild. The select options are working fine so far, but I am unable to fectch the related hindi data.

```js
var stateObject = {
  "Bihar": {
    "Begusarai": ["Bachhwara", "Bakhari", "Balia", "Barauni", "Begusarai", "Bhagwanpur", "Birpur", "Cheriya Bariyarpur", "Chhorahi", "Dandari", "Garhpura", "Khudabandpur", "Mansoorchak", "Matihani", "Nawkothi", "Sahebpur Kamal", "Samho Akha Kurha", "Teghra"],
  },
}

var stateObjectHindi = {
  "बिहार": {
    "बेगूसराय": ["बछवारा", "बखरी", "बलिया", "बरौनी", "बेगुसराय", "भगवानपुर", "बीरपुर", "चेरिया बरियारपुर", "छौराही", "डंडारी", "गढ़पुरा", "खोदाबंदपुर", "मंसूरचक", "मटिहानी", "नावकोठी", "साहेबपुर  कमाल", "साम्हो अखा कुरहा", "तेघरा"],
  },

}
window.onload = function() {
  var stateList = document.getElementById("stateList"),
    stateListHindi = document.getElementById("stateListHindi"),
    districtList = document.getElementById("districtList"),
    districtListHindi = document.getElementById("districtListHindi"),
    blockList = document.getElementById("blockList"),
    blockListHindi = document.getElementById("blockListHindi");
  for (var country in stateObject) {
    stateList.options[stateList.options.length] = new Option(country, country);

  }
  stateList.onchange = function() {

    districtList.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    blockList.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done 
    for (var state in stateObject[this.value]) {
      districtList.options[districtList.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
  }
  stateList.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
  districtList.onchange = function() {
    blockList.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done 
    var district = stateObject[stateList.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < district.length; i++) {
      blockList.options[blockList.options.length] = new Option(district[i], district[i]);
      stateListHindi.value = this.value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="state" id="stateList">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select State</option>
</select>

<select name="district" id="districtList">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select District</option>
</select>

<select name="block" id="blockList">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Block</option>
</select>
<br/> State in Hindi: <input type="hidden" class="stateListHindi" id="stateListHindi" name="stateListHindi" value="" /><br/> District in Hindi: <input type="hidden" class="districtListHindi" id="districtListHindi" name="districtListHindi" value="" /><br/>Block in Hindi: <input type="hidden" class="blockListHindi" id="blockListHindi" name="blockListHindi" value="" /><br/>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/swapnilraja1212/xvtLrb6y/3/)

Comment: Here is JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/swapnilraja1212/xvtLrb6y/3/

Comment: Please create a runnable stack snippet right in the question itself. Click "Edit" below your post, then the button that resembles `<>`.

Comment: @connexo I have added the JSFiddle Demo

Comment: We don't want external code representations on StackOverflow, **unless** a stack snippet won't do. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do .Also, whenever posting code in your questions, please make sure the code is properly formatted and coherently indented. Stack snippets help with the latter, the editor has a "Tidy" button on the left.

Comment: Where is the problem? All you need to do is inside your change event handlers, you assign the chosen select field value, to the corresponding hidden field. `stateListHindi.value = this.value;` Same for the district, and for the block (for the latter you do not have a change handler yet, so you will have to add that.)

Comment: When I edited this code with runnable stack snippet It only entered the code.

Comment: @CBroe If possible please change the snippet and show the demo

Comment: @CBroe I have already tried a lot. The basic code you wrote is nothing to relate with stateListHindi value. The both hindi and english value is two different variable has been declared. I need to get the hindi value

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to "translate" from the selected English value, to the Hindi value, okay. `Bihar` is the first property of your `stateObject`, and now you'd need to find the corresponding property - by its _position_ - in the `stateObjectHindi` object. So you would need to extract the properties from both objects first, into an array, then find the index of `Bihar` in the first one, and use that same index to then access the value in the second one. For the names you already have in array format - the blocks - this will be a bit more straight forward.

Comment: Give the process @CBroe has described above, you might like to rethink your design.  eg store the index in `new Option(country, index)` (use a different `for` structure to get the index in the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is perhaps not too well-suited for what you want here. You need to find the corresponding property in both objects, for the first two levels, by their *position* - so you will have to extract the keys first, and use `indexOf` to locate them.

So for the state first of all, that would be

```
var selectedKeyIndex = Object.keys(stateObject).indexOf(this.value);
stateListHindi.value = Object.keys(stateObjectHindi)[selectedKeyIndex];
```

Extract the keys from the English object, and find the index of the property matching the current selection in there. Then use that index, to extract the corresponding property name from the Hindi object.

Now, for the district, you'll have to do the same thing, but for one more level:

```
var selectedKeyIndex = Object.keys(stateObject[stateList.value]).indexOf(this.value);
districtListHindi.value = Object.keys(stateObjectHindi[stateListHindi.value])[selectedKeyIndex];
```

And then for the Blocks, which are in an array, you can select directly by index,

```
var selectedKeyIndex = stateObject[stateList.value][districtList.value].indexOf(this.value);
blockListHindi.value = stateObjectHindi[stateListHindi.value][districtListHindi.value][selectedKeyIndex];
```

All of it put together here: https://jsfiddle.net/6g5ad4cz/.
(I made the hidden fields into normal text fields, so that the result can be visually checked straight away.)